# RegEx Vs If statement to validate number range

Tags: java, regex

I have to validate a number falls within the range (0-255).
I can do this with Regular expression or using if statement.

RegEx:

```
\b([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b
```

Or

```
If(number>-1 && number <=255)
```

I want to know which one is better to use to validate number range.

Comment: Just do an if no need to import the regex lib.

Comment: Why'd you use `> -1` instead of `>= 0`?

Comment: All inputs are really informative, Thanks all for your inputs. I will go with simple "if" statement.

Answer (score 4):

I use a simple rule:
If you can code without regexp and keep it simple - than do it without.
Regexps gives you a lot of power, but it can be tricky to master.
In your case - the "if" code will run faster and will have much better readability.
A lot of times - regexps can amount to something which is very complex to understand and maintain as requirements change.

Comment: Upvoted for not mentioning efficiency.  I swear, regex questions attract premature optimizers worse than Kardashians attract paparazzi!

Answer (score 3):

You will probably use `String.matches()` for matching / checking. Which is *very inefficient*. It internally *compiles* the pattern, uses synchronization blah blah..

So , bottom line, avoid regexes wherever possible (Also, you will have to convert the number to a String and then use regex. What a waste of both *space* and *time*)

PS : Also note that *mathematical operations* are always handled more efficiently across platforms.

Comment: This is what I thought, but just to be sure, do you have any proof for this (official js web documentation or anything)?

Answer (score 1):

Number comparison is much efficient than String with regex comparison. By comparing number as a String is over complication.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will get you partial matches when used with the following data:

`-123`
`+12`
`!12`.

So its better to use `string comparison` to avoid unseen problems and to maintain a complex regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/11

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple and easy to understand(w.r.t your problem) I would suggest to go for If statement. But for complex validations I would suggest using regex. The reason for this is also the same - to keep it simple and easy to understand. Why use 8-10 lines of if-then blocks when you can validate the same with concise 25-30 character regex pattern! And if you put that same pattern in a .config file, you can now change the behavior of your app without recompiling. It's less code doing more work in a flexible way.

Comment: The funny part is *8 to 10 if blocks* are almost always *more efficient than 30 characters of regex* :P

Comment: Yes but it looks concised when you use regex.

Comment: The *creation* of regex is very expensive. Not to add the additional overhead of *synchronization* in `matcher` as well as the loss of *advantage* of not using *primitive types* like ints.

Comment: Well that's true but it depends on the developers perspective whether or when to use it :)

Comment: Depends very much on what you value and how efficient your software is supposed to be.